# Do I need a Content Type Hub?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, content-type-hub

We have one site collection with a bunch of subsites, and I need cross-*subsite* lookup.

Do I need to create a content-type hub?

I have Sharepoint Enterprise 2010.

*(If anyone follows along here and you happen to want the cross-subsite lookup, I used [this solution from CodePlex](https://filteredlookup.codeplex.com/).)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a content type hub with a single site collection. The benefit of the hub comes into play when you have multiple site collections in the same Web Application that share content types and you want to manage all of the content type updates in a single place (the hub).